# Number/Text formatting lost when copied in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

again, all! I have the following snippet of code which takes a number from one sheet and simply sets the column in another sheet to be the exact same information.  I have tried .value and .value2, but both of those change the formatting to where it doesn't keep my commas. So, instead of 123,456,789, it is displaying as 123456789.  This must be retained as a CSV, but I've had no luck.  And the weirdest part is that it only does it to a few different ones, but not the majority of them by far.  I'm pretty lost, as you can see, this is super simple, but the answer eludes me. Please let me know if you need any additional information. Code is

```
productws.Range("B3:B" & lr).Value2 = translatews.Range("BH3:BH" & lr).Value2
```

Comment: Value transfer does not carry over formatting. You can use [`Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) for that.

Comment: I thought using copy and paste was generally considered bad programming? Is that not correct, or ok since it's just for one line? I'm very new to this, so I really don't know, myself.

Comment: It's not bad programming, if it's needed :) Many times it isn't needed, but this is a valid use case.

Comment: Just for completion sakes, can you show a few examples through a screenshot of input/output?

Answer (score 1):

Value transfer does not carry over formatting. You can use [`Range.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) for that.

```
translatews.Range("BH3:BH" & lr).Copy Destination:=productws.Range("B3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Text` function to get a cell's value as it appears on the screen (including formatting).

`productws.Range("B3:B" & lr).Value = translatews.Range("BH3:BH" & lr).Text`

That said, it sounds like the underlying issue is that Excel is auto-formatting away the commas in your source data and assuming they're just numbers, instead of comma separated values. You can avoid this by setting the cell format of your source data to Text, instead of Numeric (select the range, right click, Format Cells, select category Text).

Comment: Ahh, that's where that messed up.  I tried the ```Text function, but it didn't work, and now I see why.  Let me try that, and I'll get back on here and comment if that did clear it up.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you actually try this? Just checking... From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text): The Text property is most often used for a range of one cell. If the range includes more than one cell, the Text property returns Null, except when all the cells in the range have identical contents and formats. In other words - `.Text` does not return an array.

Comment: Lol, just tried it with just that problem.  I'm going to include it in my existing for loop and see if that satisfies the  single cell problem.

Comment: @TradingPostLLC - I'd argue that writing to the sheet cell-by-cell is a worse programming practice (very slow and inefficient) than just implementing `Copy`, which is actually fine.

Comment: I really would like to update my code to using all arrays, but I'm not comfortable enough with arrays to do that yet, but I did have that thought in mind for my next iteration on this project. I agree with you completely!

Comment: And just ran it through the loop with no success. Copy and paste we go! Thank you both, once I get the desired result I will mark the answer and go from there!

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, so the answer is in! I gave you very fine folks what I thought was the problem, but the problem was in building the value itself.  I used commas to concatenate the various values, which caused Excel to read it as a number (but sometimes as text, if the values in the last place were only two digit vs three).  So, the answer was to change my delimiter to semicolons in all places that mattered, and it now works like a charm!  I would post here, but it spans quite a bit of code, so unless requested, I will leave this as answer.  I apologize for giving a "bad" question, and will try to do better in the future!  Thank you to everyone who was helpful, the Stack Overflow community is always trying to help out!